# javamail - Getting message body content formatting error

Tags: java, email, formatting, jakarta-mail, mime-message

When I try to retrieve the message body text from an email, it is coming out in half sentences and strange formatting. Any help would be great...

Code:

```
protected void dumpPart(Part p) throws MessagingException, IOException
    {
        if (p.isMimeType("text/plain"))
        {
            if (!p.getContent().toString().equals(null))
                System.out.println((String)p.getContent());

        }
        else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*"))
        {
            Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();

            for (int x = 0; x < mp.getCount(); x++)
            {
                dumpPart(mp.getBodyPart(x));
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

`The gist of PNM's protest in RP00-626 is that we shouldn't be able to`

`charge a transport or fuel fee for our imbalance netting and trading`

`service.`

`I aggress with PNM that our tariff language is`

`vague.`

Answer (score 1):

I think I see the problem.

You're chunking the message.

When you call `dumpPart` with each of the chunks it is printed out with a new line.  So if you message is chunked link this

```
A: The gist of PNM's protest in RP00-626 is that we shouldn't be able to
B: charge a transport or fuel fee for our imbalance netting and trading
C: service.
```

Then when you re-assemble it, you are inserting new lines after each chunk.

Doing it like this will remove the newlines.

```
protected void dumpPart(Part p, StringBuilder sb) throws MessagingException, IOException
    {
        if (p.isMimeType("text/plain"))
        {
            if (!p.getContent().toString().equals(null))
                sb.append((String)p.getContent());

        }
        else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*"))
        {
            Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();

            for (int x = 0; x < mp.getCount(); x++)
            {
                dumpPart(mp.getBodyPart(x), sb);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Implemented this and then returned `sb.toString()` but still getting the same result.

Comment: In that case, it might be worth looking at the raw encoded message.  Is it adding in new lines to the message?

Comment: It's definitely adding new line characters to do the message. However I have no way of validating if a new line character in the message has been added by the user or `javamail`...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem with your example output.  It looks like two sentences split over five lines, as it probably is in the original text/plain part.  It's possible that the original part has a Content-Type of "text/plain; format=flowed".  In that case, you'll need to implement the semantics of "format=flowed" yourself (just as you would if you were reading an html part).  JavaMail is just providing access to the data, formatting is up to you.

Comment: Could you expand on `format=flowed` as I haven't seen it in any of the docs.